# How to fix Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

Tags: java

I have just started to learn Java, however I always encounter a kind of annoying error whenever I run a program:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

It doesn't affect my programs but it's quite annoying to see it so often. I couldn't find any solutions so I hope someone can help me find out where the problem is.

By the way I'm using Kali Linux (running on VM), IntelliJ IDEA as my main Java IDE and I already had the latest JDK version installed.

Comment: This is not an error, it's a warning. Check if you have defined that `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable (are you sure it has the leading underscore?), and try to unset it. Run your code like `_JAVA_OPTIONS="" java -cp ...` as a quick try.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your answer. And yes the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` has the leading underscore. However I don't know how to unset it. Can you show me how? Thanks a lot !